# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'users'@'host'

Tags: shell, root, mysql

Mysql is making me crazy....

I know that this question has been asked 1000 times but nothing works for me... I can't connect to mysql ! This arrived after I update ubuntu 13.1

```
$> mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jeremy'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
$> mysql -u root -p****
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
$> cd my_work ; rails c
Access denied for user 'working'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql2::Error)
```

I have tried a thousand of command lines, the only thing that not show me a `permission denied` is to run mysqld with the `--skip-grant-tables` option but once started, It is like I have no users in my db, even root user ! More, I could not create or update users because of the `--skip-grant-tables`

```
$> sudo su
$> service mysql stop
$> mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
$> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('********') WHERE user="root";
 Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
 Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
$> SELECT host, user, password FROM user;
 localhost | debian-sys-maint | *5480DE723DE487F407399B5208AA09588E67850E
```

Are all my users deleted ? Is my root user deleted ? How to fix that ?!

for @user2503775, my database.yml :

```
development:
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: mysql2
  reconnect: true
  database: working
  username: working
  password: working
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Comment: Are your databases still there? Also, the password for maintenance user should be in: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Comment: I think my database are still there because when I use mysql workbench I see them. Bui If I click on a db, I have the following message : `Your connection attempt failed for user 'root' from your host to server at 127.0.0.1:3306:
  Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) `

Comment: What am I supposed to do with the password in /etc/mysql/debian.cnf ? create my users and a root user ?

Comment: Please attach your database.yml

Comment: Change your username to `root` and remove the password (it's only development). Or, if you want `working` user, follow this website http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/how-to-reset-forgot-mysql-root-password-on-unix-linux-windows/